# Удалить свойство из обьекта?

Tags: javascript, объекты, ecmascript-6

У меня есть обьект такого вида:

```
const groups = {
    tiers: {
      groups: [{name: 'test', id: 'test'}, {name: 'test2', id: 'test2'}]
    },
    applications: {
      groups: [{name: 'test11', id: 'test23'}, {name: 'test3', id: 'test3'}]
    },
    transactions: {
      groups: [{name: 'test1321', id: 'test2323'}, {name: 'test323', id: 'test323'}]
    }
  };
```

Как лучше удалить у всех `groups` поле `id`, и получить такой обьект:

```
const groups = {
    tiers: {
      groups: [{name: 'test'}, {name: 'test2'}]
    },
    applications: {
      groups: [{name: 'test11'}, {name: 'test3'}]
    },
    transactions: {
      groups: [{name: 'test1321'}, {name: 'test323'}]
    }
  };
```

Я пробовал что то такое

```
 Object.values(groups)
  .map(g => g.groups)
  .forEach(c => delete c.id)
```

Comment: замени [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) на [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас почти все правильно написано. Однако, Вы вероятно, забыли, что `map` возвращает массив из элементов. Таким образом, после `map` у Вас массив массивов `groups`. Чтобы код заработал, необходимо `map` заменить на простой `forEach`

```js
const groups = {
  tiers: {
groups: [{name: 'test', id: 'test'}, {name: 'test2', id: 'test2'}]
  },
  applications: {
groups: [{name: 'test11', id: 'test23'}, {name: 'test3', id: 'test3'}]
  },
  transactions: {
groups: [{name: 'test1321', id: 'test2323'}, {name: 'test323', id: 'test323'}]
  }
};
Object.values(groups).forEach(item => {
  item.groups.forEach(a => {
   delete a.id
  })
})

console.log(groups)
```